# Closing RabbitMQ connection blocks thread, using Pika

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

I'm connecting to RabbitMQ from a separate thread but want to allow the thread to be stopped from another thread.

```
class JobListener(threading.Thread):
    """Listens for jobs"""

    connection = None
    channel = None
    consuming = False

    def run(self):
        try:
            """Start listening for jobs"""
            self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
                pika.ConnectionParameters(host=CONN_HOST, credentials=CONN_CREDENTIALS))
            print("[JobListener] AMQP connection established.")
            self.channel = self.connection.channel()
            print("[JobListener] Channel opened.")
            self.channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE_NAME)
            print("[JobListener] Queue declared")
            self.channel.basic_consume(self.on_message, queue=QUEUE_NAME, no_ack=True)
            self.consuming = True
            print("[JobListener] Starting consumption...")
            self.channel.start_consuming()
            print("[JobListener] start_consuming() got interrupted externally.")
        finally:
            self.consuming = False

            print("[JobListener] JobListener thread finished.")

    def stop(self):
        """Stop listening for jobs"""
        self.channel.stop_consuming()
        print("[JobListener] Message consumption stopped.")
        self.channel.close()
        print("[JobListener] Channel closed.")
        self.connection.close()
        print("[JobListener] AMQP connection closed.")
        self.consuming = False

    def on_message(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        """Handle incoming message"""
        print("[x] Received %r " % body)
```

From a different thread, I'm calling either `job_listener.start()` or `job_listener.stop()`.

However, when I call `job_listener.stop()`, the inner call of `self.connection.close()` is blocked. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Pika is not thread safe (see the [FAQ](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)).

> - Is Pika thread safe?
>
>   Pika does not have any notion of threading in the code. If you want to use Pika with threading, make sure you have a Pika connection per thread, created in that thread. It is not safe to share one Pika connection across threads, with one exception: you may call the connection method add_callback_threadsafe from another thread to schedule a callback within an active pika connection.

You need to use [`add_callback_threadsafe`](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingConnection.add_callback_threadsafe)

eg.

```py
class JobListener(threading.Thread):

    ...

    def stop(self):
        """Stop listening for jobs"""
        self.connection.add_callback_threadsafe(self._stop)
        self.join()


    def _stop(self):
        self.channel.stop_consuming()
        print("[JobListener] Message consumption stopped.")
        self.channel.close()
        print("[JobListener] Channel closed.")
        self.connection.close()
        print("[JobListener] AMQP connection closed.")
        self.consuming = False
```